# WPF LostFocus of UserControl not fired

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a problem with the LostFocus event of a UserControl.

I found a couple of solutions on the net, but they don't seem to work for me.

My UserControl has a Behavior like this:

```xml
<dxmvvm:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                       Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}"
                       EventName="LostKeyboardFocus">
    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
        <dx:EventArgsToDataRowConverter />
    </dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
</dxmvvm:EventToCommand>
```

The Command just sets a flag:

```
private void ExecuteLostFocusCommand(object obj)
{
    var viewModel = obj as ITreeViewLeafViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        viewModel.IsEditing = false;
    }
}
```

This works when I click on another UserControl. But when I click on an empty space, I would expect the Window holding the UserControl would get focus and my UserControl would lose it. But this doesn't happen, even when I set the `Focusable="True"` for the Window. I also tried to Handle the `MouseDown` of the Window and Focus the Window there:

```
((Window) sender).Focus();
```

But this also doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have another focusable control in the same window?

Comment: Yes, when I click on it LostFocus is fired for the first element.

Comment: Then what's the problem? `Window.Focus` sets the Focus to the window which then focuses the first focusable control. You can't just *lose* focus, it has to be transferred to something else. Instead of the Window itself, choose something that can get the focus.

Comment: But `Window.Focus()` will not fire the LostFocus event for my UserControl.

Comment: Because your control won't loose the focus unless another control gets it. The window itself is cant maintain focus even if you set `Focusable = true` (that's the default value anyway).

Comment: Do you need to get rid of the logical focus or just keyboard focus? (2 different things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend solving this differently since *actively losing focus* isn't a very good idea (seems like you are working around a completely different, more fundamental problem), but if you **really** want to do it, this is how:

(Put this snippet into your Window_MouseDown or whatever)

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, null);
Keyboard.ClearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **PreviewLostKeyboardFocus** event of textbox control.
It fires when you click on another user control on same form or anywhere apart from that control.

```html
PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="txtDesnActArea_LostFocus"
```